# How to avoid using VLOOKUP?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have a workbook where the user can create a report then move it to a new workbook. This one takes up less than 1MB of space, and works well on my own Desktop.

In this report there are approximately 1,500 rows that use VLOOKUP to retrieve data from a dataset in the workbook itself, and I fear that my modest company's computer will experience some slowness in opening these files.

All this data are put in tables, but the value to look for is pasted by a macro during the report building process, when the tables create new rows and expand. Can I return this data in some other way? I can make VBA convert the formulas to data ranges, but at the moment I wouldn't like that.

Comment: In my experience, a VLOOKUP on 1,500 rows isn't bad. I don't know if this is an option for you, but during that report creation, could the last step be a macro that converts all formulas to text  (ie, copy and paste special as text). I guess it just depends if the final product can be static.

Comment: @Isolated that is equal to `CTRL`-`A` + Paste Special > As Text

Comment: @Fabricio\ Barbosa The sad story is that using MS-products always demands hardware performance at least close to the 75:th percentile of the hardware available at a given date.

Comment: I could use `range.formula = range.formula.value`. I just think the formulas will look ugly during a possible analysis of the report, as it will be shared and viewed on the web browser.

Comment: Refer this article: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/12/16/vlookup-excel-fastest-formula/